# Add vibration to the AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android

I am launching my Dialog window from a service class and  trying to attach vibration to my AlertDialog.Build window but with the current state the app is keeping virating all the time. I want it vibrate once when the window appears. How can I achieve that?

I appreciate any help.

```
private void stop_popup(final ArrayList<Integer> routeList) {

    int routeListSize = routeList.size();
    flag = false;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            flag = true;
        }
    }, 2 * 1000 * 60);

    if (routeListSize > 0) {

        String[] charSequence = new String[routeList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < routeList.size(); i++) {
            charSequence[i] = String.valueOf(routeList.get(i));
        }
        vibration();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Has this route arrived the stop? ");

        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(charSequence, null,
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            route_number = routeList.get(which);

                        }

                    }
                });

        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });

        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        // To launch the dialog window from the TrackingService class.
        alert.getWindow().setType(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alert.show();

        if(alert!=null && alert.isShowing() ){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            }, 1 * 1000 * 60);
        }
    }
}

public Vibrator vibration() {

    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    long[] pattern = { 0, 3000, 3000 };

    v.vibrate(pattern, 0);
    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `v.cancel()` when you want it to stop vibrating

Comment: How can access the object `v` if I want to out `v.cancel();` inside a Handler()?

Comment: @MrAsker , you can store it inside `stop_popup()` like `vibrator = vibration();`and I believe it will be accessible inside handler.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the vibration using a pattern once, you should do this:

```
v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

The repeat parameter indicates the index into the pattern array at which the repeating starts. So when you use `0`, you are literally asking it to vibrate forever.

Of course you can `v.cancel()` at any time, but you can solve your problem without the `v.cancel()`.